# (ObjC -> Swift) Convert function "init" & "textureNamed"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I get some errors when I try to convert 2 functions in Swift!

**ObjC**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *textureCache;    

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.textureCache = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
    return self;
}

- (SKTexture *)textureNamed:(NSString *)textureName {
    return _textureCache[textureName];
}
```

**Swift**

```
var textureCache: NSMutableDictionary?    

public func init() -> Self {
    return textureCache = NSMutableDictionary()
} 

public func textureNamed(textureName: String!) -> SKTexture! {
    return textureCache(textureName)
}
```

In the "init" function :

1. Expected identifier in function declaration -> (public func init ->
   Self)
2. Cannot assign a value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to a value of type 'NSMutableDictionary?' -> (return textureCache = NSMutableDictionary())

And for the "textureNamed" function :

1. Cannot invoke 'textureCache' with an argument list of type '(String!)'
   -> (return textureCache(textureName))

If someone could help me, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
class Test: NSObject {

  var textureCache = [String:SKTexture]()

  override init() {
    super.init()
  }

  func textureNamed(name: String) -> SKTexture? {
    return self.textureCache[name]
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's decompose the problem.

Swift doesn't need a return type for init and if you have a superclass, you need to call `super.init()`:

```
public func init() {
    super.init() //required if you have a superclass as the override after public
    textureCache = NSMutableDictionary()
}
```

Second problem, the method looks correct, the problem is related to the fact that `textureCache` is an Optional, so you have two solutions here.

Unwrap the variable and return the cached texture cached:

```
public func textureNamed(textureName: String!) -> SKTexture! {
    return textureCache?(textureName)
}
```

Or declare `textureCache` as non-optional value, because you are actually initializing it in the init method:

```
var textureCache: NSMutableDictionary  

public func textureNamed(textureName: String!) -> SKTexture! {
       return textureCache(textureName)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, it doesn't work in the both cases ! ^^
But you helped me a lot cuz I "found" a solution :

```
public init() {
    textureCache = NSMutableDictionary()
}

public func textureNamed(textureName: String!) -> SKTexture! {
    return textureCache?[textureName] as! SKTexture!
}
```

But I'm still not sure sure, the errors disappeared hoping it will not crash later...